# Перенос строки в .properties файле

Tags: java

Вот у меня типичный формат `properties` файла: `name=value` а что если у меня `value` довольно длинное я хочу использовать перенос строки? Это возможно?

Как-то так:

```
name=val 
ue
```

Может какие специальные символы есть для того чтобы сказать что `ue` это не новый ключ, а продолжение значения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да вы можете это сделать, экранируя обратным слешем:

```
name=val\
ue
```

Источник: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: Это как раз [обратный слэш](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0), а не прямой.

Comment: @Nofate, всегда путаю. Но это не особо важно, есть ведь пример. Однако я поправлю

Answer (score 1):

Вместо переноса строки в properties файле используйте `\n`

У вас получится такое:

```
name=val\nue
```

Comment: Нет мне нужен не перенос строки а наоборот если я переношу строку файл это игнорирует. Тоесть значение очень большое и в одну строку его записать не удобно хочу что-бы один ключ соответствовал значению на нескольких строках

Comment: в таком случае используйте способ, который рекомедует @НикитаВасильченко. Экранируйте конец строк прямым слэшем.

Comment: @Павел вот ещё пример: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8978515/784540